# React native Navigation | How to set Up Dark theme

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation, ios-darkmode, darkmode

I am practicing and new in React native and I really like React navigation.

I have been playing around **react navigation** and made custom settings like `ErrorBoundary` which it works fine.

I created one component and named it settings, from that settings component user can toggle the button go to Dark mode.

I didn't find in the documentation how to change the app's dark mood. **Can any please help me out, How to change dark mood from child component?**

**This is my router component. Where I navigate the component.**

```js
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { ThemeContext } from "styled-components";
import ErrorBoundary from "../components/errorBoundaries";
import ITheme from "../themes/types";
import IssuesRouter from "./issues/components/router";
import Settings from "./settings/Settings";
import StyleGuide from "./styleGuide";
import Itinerary from "./tasks/views/itinerary";

const tabIcon = ({ focused, color, size, route }: any) => {
  let iconName;
  if (route.name === `Tasks`) {
    iconName = focused
      ? `ios-checkmark-circle`
      : `ios-checkmark-circle-outline`;
  } else if (route.name === `Issues`) {
    iconName = focused ? `ios-warning` : `ios-warning`;
  } else if (route.name === `History`) {
    iconName = focused ? `ios-list-box` : `ios-list`;
  } else if (route.name === `Settings`) {
    iconName = focused ? `ios-settings` : `ios-settings`;
  }
  return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
};

const ApplicationRouter = () => {
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
  const theme: ITheme = useContext(ThemeContext);

  const HomeScreen = () => { 
    const { navigate } = useNavigation();
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: `pink`,
          justifyContent: `center`,
          alignItems: `center`
        }}
      >
        <Text>Home!</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => navigate(`Tasks`)} title="Open Modal" />
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <ErrorBoundary id="ApplicationRouter">
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: i =>
            tabIcon({
              ...i,
              route
            })
        })}
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: theme.linkColor,
          inactiveTintColor: theme.linkColorInactive,
          style: {
            paddingTop: 10,
            borderTopWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColorAlt2
          }
        }}
        lazy={false}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="Tasks" component={Itinerary} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Issues" component={IssuesRouter} />
        <Tab.Screen name="History" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} /> //THIS IS MY SETTING COMPONENT WHERE I WANT CHANGE MY DARK MOOD 
        <Tab.Screen name="Style guide" component={StyleGuide} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};

export default ApplicationRouter;
```

**This is my setting component**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Switch, View } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
  const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Switch
        trackColor={{ false: "#767577", true: "#81b0ff" }}
        thumbColor={isEnabled ? "#f5dd4b" : "#f4f3f4"}
        ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
        onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
        value={isEnabled}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to switch the theme using ThemeContext ?

Comment: yes,  I am trying use ThemeContext.

Comment: can you share the code for the theme context you use?

Comment: Navigation provides its own themes so you dont have to use another library for that https://reactnavigation.org/docs/themes/#using-the-current-theme-in-your-own-components

Answer (score 1):

I see is an old question, nevertheless I want to answer in case someone is browsing this issue.

At the current version of react-native- navigation (6*.0) is very simple to set up a theme manager the whole App with few boiler plate code

***NOTE!!!***:

**This pacakges must be installed in order for this to work (All all part of React-navigation)**:

```js
npm install @react-navigation/native
# 2 Main dependencie
npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
# 3 Addittional Package (Stack)
npm install @react-navigation/native-stack react-native-gesture-handler

# 4 Additional Dependency:
npm install @react-navigation/stack react-native-gesture-handler
```

### FULL WORKING CODE WITH MINIMUN CODE

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer,DefaultTheme, DarkTheme,useTheme,} from '@react-navigation/native';  // IMPORT THEMES HERE!!! 
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

function SettingsScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Profile"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const { colors } = useTheme();  // USE THIS In order to get the Current Themes used
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: colors.card }}>
          <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>Button!</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      <Button
        title="Go to Settings"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer theme={ DarkTheme  }> // HERE THE KEY PART, Just add the Theme and the Whole App uses it (a part of text)  
        <Stack.Navigator  initialRouteName="Home">
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

### EXPLANATION

1. Import this

   import {NavigationContainer,DefaultTheme, DarkTheme,useTheme,} from '@react-navigation/native';  // IMPORT THEMES HERE!!!
2. On the NavigationContainer add prop `theme`

   ```js
    <NavigationContainer theme={ DarkTheme  }>
   ```

Note that a theme must follow this Javasrict Object Structure:

```js
const MyTheme = {
  dark: false,
  colors: {
    primary: 'rgb(255, 45, 85)',
    background: 'rgb(242, 242, 242)',
    card: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
    text: 'rgb(28, 28, 30)',
    border: 'rgb(199, 199, 204)',
    notification: 'rgb(255, 69, 58)',
  },
};
```

3. Access the current selected Theme with `useTheme` function. The texts for instance don't get updated and you wouold need to set up manually

   ```js
   const { colors } = useTheme();  // USE THIS In order to get the Current
   ```

   // Use it like this
   <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>Button!

**By the way, this is how the `DefaultThem` `DarkTheme` Objects are:

```js
// DEFAULT LIGHT THEME
const DefaultTheme = {
    dark: false,
    colors: {
        primary: 'rgb(0, 122, 255)',
        background: 'rgb(242, 242, 242)',
        card: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        text: 'rgb(28, 28, 30)',
        border: 'rgb(216, 216, 216)',
        notification: 'rgb(255, 59, 48)',
    },
};

// DEFAULT DARK THEME
const DarkTheme = {
    dark: true,
    colors: {
        primary: 'rgb(10, 132, 255)',
        background: 'rgb(1, 1, 1)',
        card: 'rgb(18, 18, 18)',
        text: 'rgb(229, 229, 231)',
        border: 'rgb(39, 39, 41)',
        notification: 'rgb(255, 69, 58)',
    },
};
```

### Documentation

- [React Navigation - Themes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/themes/)

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks. Note that this works - for the most part - on React Navigation 5.x as well. I found it tricky to get the tabbar labels and icons to use theme colors, and this solved it!